# How can i test an API call in vuejs using jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs

im having this method in my component that makes an API call with axios, I checked the docs on how to test it but I cant seem to figure out how to do so. Any help would be appreciated.

```
loadContents() {
  axios.get('/vue_api/content/' + this.slug).then(response => {
    this.page_data = response.data.merchandising_page
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
},
```

Comment: Mock out axios? See the docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`moxios`](https://github.com/axios/moxios) or [`axios-mock-adapter`](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter) to automatically mock Axios requests. I prefer the latter for developer ergonomics.

Consider this `UserList` component that uses Axios to fetch user data:

```
// UserList.vue
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      users: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async loadUsers() {
      const { data } = await axios.get("https://api/users");
      this.users = data;
    }
  }
};
```

With `axios-mock-adapter`, the related test stubs the Axios `GET` requests to the API URL, returning mock data instead:

```
import axios from "axios";
const MockAdapter = require("axios-mock-adapter");
const mock = new MockAdapter(axios);

import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import UserList from "@/components/UserList";

describe("UserList", () => {
  afterAll(() => mock.restore());
  beforeEach(() => mock.reset());

  it("loads users", async () => {
    mock
      .onGet("https://api/users")
      .reply(200, [{ name: "foo" }, { name: "bar" }, { name: "baz" }]);

    const wrapper = shallowMount(UserList);
    await wrapper.vm.loadUsers();
    const listItems = wrapper.findAll("li");
    expect(listItems).toHaveLength(3);
  });
});
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xpp40qnl3o?module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FUserList.spec.js&previewwindow=tests)

Comment: @user127 If you want the network call to hit the server, then you don't want to mock at all.